# How do I conditionally format by greater/less value of data ranges of values on different sheets?

Tags: excel, formatting

I have an excel workbook that is tracking sports stats. I am trying to track college basketball, so the columns are the exact same, but the rows include player rosters which change year by year (each sheet = each year's roster/stats). Some players stay, while others leave. For the ones that stay, I want to compare their previous year's stats [example of stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiogY.png)

For the attached example set of values, I want green formatting for the cell if the statistic is a higher value than last year, and red if it is a lower value (bonus points for yellow formatting with same). I was hoping to apply the logic across each of these cells, or for the full set of values. I have gotten as far as naming the above collection of values on different sheets (ex. "Year1Stats", "Year2Stats"), but I am not sure what to do from there. I feel like it's a simple solution, but struggling to get there.

I have messed around with the pre set highlight rules Excel offers and tried to make custom formula rules but I am not really getting close. I have tried to find StackOverflow or other google threads on a problem like this, and have found similar issues, but I am struggling to apply answers to this direct problem because of my lack of Excel experience.

Comment: You will need `indirect()` function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

let me show you the demo at first to align with you.
[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCEIV.png)

Assum your A column is showing the name, and we use the name to map between sheets.

So what we need to do is, map column A between sheets to get row, then map the correspond column in the row.

Suppose we are applying the formula to B2, current sheet name is "Sheet1", and the sheet you want to compare with is "Sheet2", then the formula will be:

```
=B2 < INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(TRUE,$A2=(Sheet2!$A:$A),0))
```

(BTW, this formula is [array formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d))

Use MATCH(TRUE,$A2=(Sheet2!$A:$A) to searching the row.
The syntax [Sheet Name]![Range] is the syntax to query the field cross the sheets.

Due to the compare target is B2 in Column B, so use the Sheet2!B:B in the below part:
INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(TRUE,$A2=(Sheet2!$A:$A),0))

By above formula, we will get the B2's value in the Sheet2.
Then compare with B2 in the current sheet, the problem solved, you can [copy the format](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-format-painter-4bb415a9-d4e4-42b7-b579-170adc594e40#:%7E:text=Use%20the%20Format%20Painter.%201%20Select%20the%20text,4%20To%20stop%20formatting%2C%20press%20ESC.%20See%20More.) to the field you want.

Hope this help.